# How to use DecimalFormater in java?

Tags: java, decimalformat

i am new to the java, iam facing an issue in my task with `DecimalFormat`

when i give integer number it should not have any decimals,
if i give decimal number it should print decimal value

i used the `DecimalFormater` as below

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
decimalFormat.applyPattern("0");

System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(123456789.2569));
```

here it is printing without decimals.
i replace my patern with
`decimalFormat.applyPattern("#.##");`

in this case when i give 299
it is printing 3

but it should print 299 
how to do it?

finally, if i give `265` it should be `265`, if i give `265.36` it should be `265.36`

Comment: Use `"0.##"` pattern.

Comment: you should add which java version you use. in jdk7 `"#.##"` works as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `#.##` pattern you will get only the first digit and the rest of your number will be treated as fraction digits.

And that explains why you got `3` when you inputed `299` because with this pattern `299` is treated as `2.99` and then rounded to `3`.

So try to use this pattern instead:

```
decimalFormat.applyPattern("###.##");
```

For further information about it you can take a look at:

- **[Customizing Formats in Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)**
- [**Java DecimalFormat | tutorials.jenkov.com**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html)